# this axios api call returns an empty array for the call, but the second one returns a value

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to use the context below to fetch the data from the api, then pass it down to other components. The data is from unsplash, so I would like to filter it out first using a keyword set by the user. However, the first array returned by the function is empty, but if I console.log() it, I get all the data as expected

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const ImageContext = createContext();

export const ImageContextProvider = ({children}) => {

const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const count = 15;
const start = 1;

const getImages = async (keyword) => {
    await axios.get(`api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}&keyword=${keyword}`)
        .then(res => setImages(res.data.results));

}

return ( 
    <ImageContext.Provider value={{images, getImages: getImages }}>
        {children}
    </ImageContext.Provider>
 );
 }
```

This is the component that passes the keyword to the context that will be used to fetch data from the API

```
 import React, { useState, useContext} from 'react';
  import { ImageContext } from '../../Context/ImageContext';

  export const SearchBar = () => {
      const { getImages, images } = useContext(ImageContext);
      const[keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

      const searchImages = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      await getImages(keyword);
      console.log(images);
   }

    return ( 
    <form onSubmit={searchImages}>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Search Images' value={keyword} onChange={(e) => 
        setKeyword(e.target.value)}/>
        <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
 );
 }
```

Comment: the state is changed every render. When you console.log after the `await` statement, you won't get the updated state. However, if you render the images, you should see the update

Comment: @kkesley Thank you, it works. I rendered the component and everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your `getImages()` function:

```js
const getImages = async (keyword) => {
  await axios.get(`api/photos?...`).then(...);
}
```

If I’m right that is a wrong construction as you’re mixing and `await` and a `then()`. Furthermore, your `getImages()` is not returning a value. I think the following solves your problem:

```js
const getImages = async (keyword) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`api/photos?...`);
  setImages(res.data.results);
  return res.data.results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there :)

Since you are using React hooks, you need `useEffect` so that you can be able to send Http request. It is equivalent to `componentDidMount.

How to use it?

```js
import React, {useState, createContext, useEffect} from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
    const result =  axios.get(`api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}&keyword=${keyword}`)
        .then(res => setImages(res.data.results));  // remember to update your state


  }, []);  // don't forget to pass an empty array
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you advise on how I can pass the search keyword to the hook?